# How do I programmatically find ILASM.EXE in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net

My program needs to call `ILASM`, but it keeps moving on me. Is there a registry setting or some other value that my program can read so I don't need to hard code the path?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it keeps moving on you?

Comment: The path varies depending on which version of .NET you have. Even going from .NET 4.0 RC  to .NET 4.0 Gold currently breaks my compiler.

Answer (score 5):

From the SDK Microsoft.Build.Utilities namespace, the [ToolLocationHelper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.toollocationhelper.aspx) can be used like so:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities; 

// Use ToolLocationHelper to find ILASM.EXE in the Framework directory
ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkFile("ILAsm.exe", TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.VersionLatest);
```

Taken from [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a few libraries that are like ILAsm that people have recommended:

1. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/6a34a558-ab57-424f-a799-f0fc458105c1/default.aspx
2. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7e979ed3-416b-43b6-993b-308a160831b6&displaylang=en

You might want to use those (or CodeDom -> C#) instead of calling out to a program.

Comment: This is part of a research project to write a .NET compiler, so using those libraries would somewhat defeat the purpose for me.

Comment: @Jonathan: The first link just assembles MSIL code, so that might be able to help you without interfering with your compiler work.

Comment: Interesting, is the source code avaialble? I'm using some things that are not currently exposed by any .NET language, so I'm a little concerned about running into something they don't support.

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't know if source code is available for either of those.

Answer (score 1):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework, look for InstallRoot. Add the .net version number to the path in InstallRoot and you've got it.